# DNS resolution does not work in virtual machine with proxy

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, vmware

I am working on a windows host machine on a private network. This machine is connected to the internet via a proxy, which allows me to navigate successfully using browsers, even though I cannot use tools like ping or nslookup on external sites, as I get a DNS resolution error.

The problem is that I have a virtual machine that I imported in VMWare, with NAT connection, which is unable to connect to the internet (I still get DNS resolution errors). Unfortunately, this particular VM needs internet connection for its very first booting, so I cannot in anyway edit its network settings - I can only intervene on the host and on the VMWare workstation.

How can I solve this DNS problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are the operating systems of host & guest?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and if you succeeded anyway, through some http-VPN from your Windows system for example, it would probably be against the policy of the network owner.

It is not a DNS problem. It's a security and policy problem.

The network owner has decided that, for access to the Internet, you must go through a proxy. Your Windows system therefore must only access the Internet via the proxy. So any direct access from your workstation to the Internet will be blocked by the network owner. Whether it is DNS traffic, or any other protocol (I assume your virtual machine uses DNS to access a real machine), it will be blocked.

You should ask your network owner if there are provisions for these kind of connections to the Internet. These provisions may vary from a separate VLAN to running VMWARE on a specific server. And it may also be just "no".

Answer (score 0):

Expending on Ljm answer: If you just need it once, I would suggest to use your smart phone for the internet connections on your host. Afterwards you can setup the proxy via your regular internet connection.